# Dataflow really slow, wordcount can't process over 2k msg/second

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Im trying to benchmark some stream processing engines, flink, spark, etc for research purposes.

#### Description

On GKE i can deploy Kafka/Flink with about 1 vcpu and 1GB mem for all pod instances a can process comfortably about **50k messages/second per instance**.

In Dataflow with 2vcpus and 7.5GB mem per instance, im getting about **2k messages/second per instance**..

#### Context

Im using as generic jobs as possible, wordcount in particular. In the Dataflow pipeline I even migrated to PubSub instead of Kafka bc i was considering that to be a potential issue.

The workload going into PubSub is about 70k messages/second. The data is lines of text from huckleberry fin, probably <1mb per msg.

#### Question

I cant seem to find any reasonable explanations or information as to why the performance is so different between these systems. Can anyone here help me?

What for instance would be the expected performance for the generic wordcount example reading from pubsub ?

> I can post code on request

Comment: Can you give an overview of the pipeline? i.e., what sources and sinks you are trying to use.

Comment: source is PubSub as i mentioned, sink is printing to console.
Heres a status report showing the pipeline visually: https://github.com/peterbangert/msc_thesis/blob/main/status_reports/Status_Report_05122022.pdf

heres the source for the beam job: https://github.com/peterbangert/msc_thesis/blob/main/beam/streaming_wordcount.py

Comment: Sorry I just got back to this. Link doesn't work for me.

Comment: apologies, i just made the repo public

Comment: Thanks! Can you also share the Kafka/Flink code, to make sure we aren't comparing different things?

Comment: Heres the flink wordcount job:
https://github.com/peterbangert/msc_thesis/blob/main/flink/quickstart/src/main/java/org/myorg/quickstart/WordCount.java

Comment: Also i just changed the fixed window length in the streaming-wordcount.py job to 1 second, as i thought that might be a bottleneck, but im gettitng effectively the same results.

Comment: @BrunoVolpato im setting the repo back to private, i need the space for my project. lmk if you look at this again i can make it unprivate